# Zooming effect without pinch image

Tags: android, libgdx, zooming

I want zoom an image, but without touching it and after some time delay, like 30 seconds, what I tried was implementing Gesturelistner and in zoom
Camera.zoom*0.5 for x ,y.

Can zoom can be done with tween? What would an example be?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to be zoomed without touching it, then the gesture listener has nothing to do with it.

Make a timer, and a flag.

```
float timetozoom = 0;
boolean zoomed = false;
```

Then add delta to it every render to check when 30 seconds have passed. When that happens, zoom it and check the flag.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if (!zoomed) {
        timetozoom += delta;
        if (timetozoom>=30) {
            camera.zoom = camera.zoom*0.5F;
            zoomed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Other thing I tried was image.setscale(1f, 0.5f)  , it is working but directly on loading

Answer (score 0):

Create a canvas. Draw the image inside the canvas. Use a surfaceView to hold the canvas. Then use a timer to do zoom or translate or whatever operations you need to do. You would find it best to use matrix manipulations to do your rotating, translating, zooming, etc. Examples are in the SDK folder.

If you are not touching the screen, I wonder how you would trigger or fire GestureListeners. You are better off using canvas and triggering onDraw() on a timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tween engine for that. It is so simple.

In create, you just draw your image with scale down using tween. And after setting some delay (30 seconds) you call the tween again with scale up to original size.

Or:

If you don't want to use the tween engine, then just draw your image with scale down and take a timer which calculates the time. And once the timer reaches 30 seconds you just scale up your image.